# Rstudio is stalling on install_github. Why?

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I'm having an annoying problem. On Rstudio, when I run install_github, I'm given the option to update package. But if I select "All" to update packages, the terminal shows me a list of packages that have newer binary version...but then doesn't return the cursor, so I can't actually select anything! I'm just stuck there, waiting for install_github() to return, and it never does. Any leads on what causes this or how to stop it?

```
> install_github("yonghah/esri2sf")
Downloading GitHub repo yonghah/esri2sf@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                               
2: CRAN packages only                
3: None                              
4: vctrs    (0.6.2  -> 0.6.3 ) [CRAN]
5: Rcpp     (1.0.10 -> 1.0.11) [CRAN]
6: cpp11    (0.4.3  -> 0.4.4 ) [CRAN]
7: jsonlite (1.8.4  -> 1.8.7 ) [CRAN]
8: curl     (5.0.0  -> 5.0.1 ) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 1
vctrs    (0.6.2  -> 0.6.3 ) [CRAN]
Rcpp     (1.0.10 -> 1.0.11) [CRAN]
cpp11    (0.4.3  -> 0.4.4 ) [CRAN]
jsonlite (1.8.4  -> 1.8.7 ) [CRAN]
curl     (5.0.0  -> 5.0.1 ) [CRAN]
Installing 5 packages: vctrs, Rcpp, cpp11, jsonlite, curl
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/holtd/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
Rcpp     1.0.10 1.0.11              TRUE
cpp11     0.4.3  0.4.4             FALSE
jsonlite  1.8.5  1.8.7              TRUE

[[Notice no carat to enter a line; the code is still running with no option to interact]]
```

Comment: No idea off the top of my head. Is this specific to the RStudio IDE? Have you tried it in `Rterm.exe` instead to make sure of it? If it does the same, then the [tag:rstudio] tag doesn't apply, and it changes the scope of this. In my experience, when I get a message like that, I tend to say "none" and then update them manually, but that's mostly because I tend to manage my package versions tightly.

Comment: Are there any indications (network i/o, disk i/o, cpu usage) that something is churning in the background?

Comment: Please be aware that RStudio is just and IDE that calls R.  You need to verify that cmd-line, or other GUIs such as rgui.app, etc. fail as well.  Further, can you install from CRAN and bioconductor?